# JPA Inheritance Two Or More Superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I made a research about Inheritance in JPA and [resources](https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) that I found uses just one superclass for each entity. But there is not an example that uses 2 or more superclass.

What about this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = “Abstract_One”)
public abstract class AbstractOne {

    @Id
    protected Long id;
    …
}

@Entity(name = “A”)
@DiscriminatorValue(“A”)
public class A extends AbstractOne {

    @Column
    private int a;

    …
}

@Entity(name = “B”)
@DiscriminatorValue(“B”)
public class B extends A {

    @Column
    private int b;

        …
}
```

**Is it possible to do that?**

**If it is possible, which Inheritance Strategy allows that and gives the best data consistency?**

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine only the following example

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class A
{
   ...
   @Id
   @Column(name = "RECID")
   public Long getId()
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class B extends A
{
...
   @Column(name = "COL1")
   public String getColumn1()
...
}

@Entity(name="INH_TAB1")
public class C extends B
{
   ...
   @Column(name = "COL2")
   public String getColumn2()
   ...
}
```

Also at the excellent book *"Java Persistence with Hibernate" by Bauer, King, Gregory* I found the following plase what can be useful in the context of this question:

> 6.5 Mixing inheritance strategies
>
> You can map an entire inheritance hierarchy with the TABLE_PER_CLASS,
>   SINGLE_TABLE, or JOINED strategy. You can’t mix them — for example, to switch from a
>   table-per-class hierarchy with a discriminator to a normalized table-per-subclass 
>   strategy. Once you’ve made a decision for an inheritance strategy, you have to stick  with it. This isn’t completely true, however. By using some tricks, you can switch
>   the mapping strategy for a particular subclass. For example, you can map a class 
>   hierarchy to a single table, but, for a particular subclass, switch to a separate 
>   table with a foreign key–mapping strategy, just as with table-per-subclass.

However, I can not imagine any real case when such complex inheritance hierarchy will be required/useful and also it can affect performance.

Comment: I have an abstract User class that contains general information such as name, surname, email. I have 3 more entity that extends from the User table. 1) GoogleUser who authenticate with Gmail. 2)MyAppUser who logs in with username password. 3) Staff this contains a ManyToOne relationship with a Bussines entity this field shows that this user is an employee of the Bussines entity also this type of user has to log in with username password. So it extends from MyAppUser.

Comment: Can GoogleUser at the same time be MyAppUser/Staff and vice versa?

Comment: GoogleUser extends User;
MyAppUser extends User;
Staff extends MyAppUser

Comment: A user with a goole accaunt after the lapse of time can become a your app user.
Your app user after the lapse of time can create a goole accaunt for himself.
So, if A is B and B is A then A and B should have the same type.
Please keep in mind also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).